# How to add an object to a manytomany field in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, many-to-many, relationship

I have two models (Group and Contact). A Group can have many Contacts and a Contact can be in many Groups.

I can create contacts but I can´t create groups right now.

When I validate form.is_valid() it returns false and the error I'm getting is

```
{'contacts': [ValidationError(['Enter a list of values.'])]}
```

What am I missing here?

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    # Fields
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='groups')
```

forms.py

```
class CreateGroupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ["name", "contacts"]
        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(attrs={
                "placeholder" : "",
                "class": "form-control"
            }),
            'contacts': Select(attrs={
                "placeholder" : "",
                "class": "form-control"
            })
        }

class CreateContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Nombre",
                "class": "form-control"
            }),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Apellido",
                "class": "form-control"
            })
        }
```

views.py

```
def create_group(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            group = form.save(commit=False)
            group.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors.as_data())
            form = CreateGroupForm()

        return render(request, 'create-group.html', {'form':form})
    elif request.method == "GET":
        form = CreateGroupForm(request.POST or None)
        return render(request, "create-group.html", { 'form' : form})
```

Comment: `Select` is not a valid widget, that should be `SelectMultiple`.

Comment: How do you render this form by the way?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#select according to this Select widget is correct

Comment: `Select` *is* a widget, but not a widget that should be used for a `MultipleModelChoiceField`, just like a `FileInput` widget makes no sense for a `BooleanField`.

Comment: Your view also can not save the `ManyToManyField`, if it would succeed in validating, because of the `commit=False`: https://hapytex.github.io/django-antipatterns/antipatterns/using_commit_false_when_altering_the_instance_in_a_modelform.html and see https://hapytex.github.io/django-antipatterns/antipatterns/do_not_use_request_post_or_none.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `ManyToManyField`, it makes not much sense to use a [**`Select`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select), since that selects only a *single* element, a [**`SelectMultiple`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SelectMultiple) is constructed to select mulitple objects.

You should also take a look to the HTML form whether it indeed submits values for the `contact` field. You can do that by inspecting the browser data.

Nevertheless, even if you get this working, by using `commit=False`, the form can not save the many-to-many field. Indeed, in order to save records in a many-to-many field, first the `Group` object should be saved, since the [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) has `ForeignKey`s to the `Contact` and `Group`, and thus these records need to be created first. It is also better *not* to construct a new `Form` in case the form is not valid, since then the errors will be reported when you render that form:

```
def create_group(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # ← no commit=False
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
        # do not create a new form.
    else:
        form = CreateGroupForm()
    return render(request, "create-group.html", { 'form' : form})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.